# GLSL "out" 4.2 to 1.2

Tags: macos, opengl, glsl

I'm trying port a GLSL 4.2 to 1.2 (Because I'm using a mac), however, I'm not sure how I can convert an out parameter to 1.2 (as it generates an error).

```
out vec3 vNormal;
out vec2 texcoord; 
out vec3 vPosition;
```

The compiler error is as following.

```
Invalid qualifiers 'out' in global variable context
ERROR: 0:13: Invalid qualifiers 'out' in global variable context
ERROR: 0:14: Invalid qualifiers 'out' in global variable context
ERROR: 0:19: Use of undeclared identifier 'texcoord'
ERROR: 0:20: Use of undeclared identifier 'vNormal'
ERROR: 0:21: Use of undeclared identifier 'vPosition'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GLSL 1.30 and above `out` qualifier represents a shader stage output. What that means for 1.20 and below depends on *which* shader stage you're talking about.

Since you're using identifiers like `texcoord` and `vNormal`, I'm guessing that you are writing a vertex shader. Then the keyword you should use is `varying`. Your fragment shader inputs that correspond to these should also be `varying` too.